# Assign a new value to pointer on keyPress

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers

I have a program in which I am drawing some images on the screen with the following code.

```
ImageViewer : Image {
public:
ImageViewer(string path){
}
void drawImage(){
Image::draw(widthHeight);
}
private:
Rectangle widthHeight;
}
```

Now, in my main program I am using the Image Viewer in the following manner-

```
string imgP = "someImage.png";
ImageViewer *imgV = new ImageViewer(imgP);
```

At the keypress, I have to changes the image path, so I do something like:
imgV = new ImageViewer(newImagePath);

My application is working fine but a times stops showing the images on screen and I have been trying to track down the reason. One thing I had in my mind to ask is about the pointer
When I assign a `new ImageViewer(newImagePath)` to the `imgV` pointer, where does the previous `imgV` value go? (Is it self destroyed or I should be manually doing it?)

I am not sure if I am picking up grabgae values or anything like that because of which the images might not be appearing but just wanted to check if this could be a probable reason as well. (Still checking internal implementations of draw and other functions inside image)

Comment: you're leaking ImageViewers.  you need to delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not itself a managed language.  Each time you say

```
imgV = new ImageViewer();
```

You allocate a new instance of the `ImageViewer` class and assign its memory address to `imgV`.  The previous memory address stored in `imgV` is lost, and is never deallocated.

You must explicitly call `delete` on `imgV` before you assign it a new value

Comment: Deleting the previous imgV gives error. After I delete imgV, I can't just say imgV = new ImageViewer('ImagePath.png'); How do I delete the imgV before assigning then?

Comment: While it's true that standard C++ is not managed, that is unrelated to  the problem.  You can have a un-managed garbage collected framework.

Comment: @thang very true, it is possible that in this framework `new` is overloaded to return a managed pointer

Comment: @DanF: I think that error might be because I am trying to access `imgV` that has been deleted already. Before doing `new` I had used `delete imgV`

Comment: You need to paste some exact code, and the exact error, this sounds like you are doing something seriously wrong

Comment: I'll jus write it down as soon as I have the compiler and the code in reach. Btw, can you recommend a profiler to detect these problems? I'm on Windows, Codeblocks, c++

Comment: Detect what problems specifically, memory leaks?  That I don't know too much about, I typically do may own management

Comment: Yes, asked about memory profiler (to detect leaks / other similar problems

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the previous object safely.

At keyPress do something like this.

```
string newImagePath= "someNewImage.png";
ImageViewer *imgV_temp = new ImageViewer(newImagePath);
delete imgV;
imgV = imgV_temp;
```